How to clean up resources on stopping Wincc OA Ctrl Manager
In a WinCC OA project we run several Ctrl manager scripts who run cyclically using an endless loop and a delay.
main()
{
  while(true)
  {
    //do stuff cyclically

    delay(1,0);
  }
}

Before the endless loop we set up resources (files, tcp connections) which we use in the while loop. What is the correct way of ending the while loop on stopping the ctrl manager via the WinCC OA Console (normal stop), so I can correctly close the used resources after the while loop?

The short answer is, it depends on the version you are using.
Before going into detail about the different versions here, we first need to clarify what even happens when someone clicks on the "stop manager" button in the console window.
The short answer for this:
A bunch of control code that finally leads to a message being sent via TCP/IP from the UI manager that is hosting the console panel to the Pmon process. The message that is being sent is simply composed according to the Pmon protocol as described in the documentation. The pmon itself receives the message and now sends a terminate signal (SIG_TERM) to the (control) manager that shall be stopped.
Even if it might sound in some way complicated, it isn't but it is outside of the scope of control (the programming language and it's hosted environment). So obviously that's a problem for your use case.
version >= 3.18
You are lucky and hopfully happy as since this version, control provides a function called sysConnect() which allows to connect to certain system events. One of these events is exitRequested which is triggered once the manager is requested to exit.
The documentation states the following:

This event is triggered the first time a CTRL manager is requested to
exit, e.g. either by losing the connection to the event manager or by
a stop request from pmon (e.g. project shutdown) or a SIGTERM signal.
Exiting is done in the following steps:

stop all running scripts (threads/CTRL-modules)
start "exitRequested" event callback threads
disconnect everything (e.g. dpConnect, query connects, alertConnect, sysConnect)

When the last thread started for the exitRequest event will stop, the manager stops as well. Be careful that the started threads will not take too long, since on a project shutdown pmon will kill the CTRL manager when it does not terminate in the defined number of seconds (set via console panel). When a second exit request happens while the "exit requested" threads are still running, the manager will terminate immediately without starting any threads again.
The callback will get the exit code (int) as argument.
Note:
Can only be used within the context of a CTRL manager.
Example
callback(string event, int exitCode)

So with that knowledge your script could look something like this:
main()
{
  sysConnect("exitRequestedCallback", "exitRequested");

  while (true)
  {
    DebugTN("Still alive");
    delay(1);
  }
}

void exitRequestedCallback(string event, int exitCode)
{
  DebugTN(event, exitCode);
  DebugTN("Bye bye");
}

Once the manager has received the signal to terminate, it will simply execute the 3 steps from the documentation that are mentioned above.
But what does that actually mean?
It means that the thread hosting the main function will get terminated and you have no control over it, don't know when it happens and cannot prevent it. It could be terminated in the midst of some crucial operation like dumping data into a database, a file or something else. It is not guaranteed, that the thread runs until it hits your delay(1, 0) and is only terminated then. If you have some kind of long running calculation, it might very well be terminated during that calculation. Only after stopping (or actually terminating) the thread(s), the callback gets called and your "cleanup code" can be run.
version < 3.18
You are neither lucky nor happy (I guess) as (to my knowledge) there is no easy way to solve your issue.
1st Proposal:
Do not stop the manager via the "stop manager" button but by using some kind of command you send to the manager. This can be either done via a datapoint to which the manager is connected to or via other means of communication (network, filesystem, etc.) - whatever fits your needs.
2nd Proposal:
Modify the script in the "clicked event" of the "stopManager" button in the console panel (panels/projAdmin/console.pnl) in the way that it incorporates the first proposal. Simply check whether it is "your" control manager that has to be stopped and if so, don't call console_stopManager() but your code instead.
Therefore you might need to modify your script to something like this:
bool shallExit = false;

main()
{
  ConnectToCommandDP();

  while (!shallExit)
  {
    DebugTN("Still alive");
    delay(1);
  }

  // Do some cleanup stuff here
}

void ConnectToCommandDp()
{
  dpConnect("CommandReceived", false, <Place your datapoint name here>);
}

void CommandReceived(string datapointName, string command)
{
  switch (command)
  {
    case "shutdown":
      ExecuteShutdownCommand();
      break;

    default:
      // Place error handling for unknown commands here
      break;
  }
}

void ExecuteShutdownCommand()
{
  shallExit = true;
}

I hope that leads you in the right direction 
